# Use PUT to upload file with TIdHTTP

Tags: delphi, indy, transifex

I'd like to upload a file using PUT on TIdHtttp. I found an answer from Remy Lebeau saying to not use PUT, but use POST instead.

But, in my case I can't do it because I'm using a third API, and it specifies that I need to use PUT. If I try to use POST, it returns me a message saying that the Method is not allowed.

Basically, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Response := TStringStream.Create;
DS := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
DS.AddFile('fileUpload2', 'C:\Users\r.rezino\Desktop\teste.po', 'application/octet-stream');
FHttpComunication.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
FHttpComunication.Put(UrlCmd, DS, Response);
```

But when I do it, I get a `500 - Internal server error`.

If I remove the:

```
FHttpComunication.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
```

I get `400 - Bad Request`.

I already tried to do the request directly from browser (Advanced REST client - chrome) and it works. So the API is working. The header of the message when it works is:

```
PUT /api/2/project/XXXXXXXX/resource/export1po/translation/en/ HTTP/1.1
HOST: www.XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com
authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXX
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryPWT8bUdkQ1ZVLHdL
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.8
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
content-length: 1936   

------WebKitFormBoundaryPWT8bUdkQ1ZVLHdL
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload2"; filename="teste.po"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

The code is not here, but yes I configured the authorization information, it's working, I can check this because I can use others call to API.

**Update**

This is the API that I'm trying to use `PUT`: http://docs.transifex.com/api/translations/#put

Ways that I tried:

1) This one return `500 - Internal Server Error`. I tried it creating the DS object with content type `application/octet-stream` too. But I got the same error.

```
Response := TStringStream.Create;
DS := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
DS.AddFile('fileUpload2', 'C:\Users\r.rezino\Desktop\teste.po', 'multipart/form-data');
try
    FHttpComunication.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data';
    FHttpComunication.Put(UrlCmd, DS, Response);
    Result := Response.DataString;
finally
    Response.Free;
    DS.Free;
end;
```

2) The way that was suggested on answers, but It's not working. I got the error `500` too.

```
PutData := TFileStream.Create('C:\Users\r.rezino\Desktop\teste.po', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
Response := TStringStream.Create;
try
    FHttpComunication.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data'; //I tried with and without it 
    FHttpComunication.Put(UrlCmd, PutData, Response);
    Result := Response.DataString;
finally
    Response.Free;
    PutData.Free;
end;
```

Comment: Provide full code with all the headers you set. Last parameter in the `AddFile` procedure should be `application/octet-stream`. Do NOT set `ContentType` manually if you don't use `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`. Otherwise use `RequestContentType` function as I mentioned. Save your headers from `TIdHTTP.Request.RawHeaders.Text` or use `OnIdHTTPHeadersAvailable` event and compare your headers. If you send exactly the same request, it has to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That API is broken by design. You should not mix `multipart/form-data` and `PUT`. You should send it like this

```
FPutData:=TFileStream.Create('yourfile.dat', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
FHTTP.Put('http://...', FPutData, FResponseStream);
```

But if it does not work, the problem is probably that you don't set a correct `ContentType`, it does not include boundary. Fix it like this

```
FHTTP.Request.ContentType:=DS.RequestContentType;
```

Where `DS` is your `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`.

Comment: `TIdMultipartFormDataStream` is intended to be used with `Post()`, and that version of `Post()` sets the `ContentType` internally, with boundary.  If you `Put()` a `TIdMultipartFormDataStream`, then yes, you have to set the `ContentType` manually, and should use the `RequestContentType` for that.

Comment: It's not working! I still get Bad Request. I tried both cases. I odd more information on question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem. It was about the boundary that I must to set. So the final result is:

```
DS := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
DS.AddFile('fileUpload2', 'C:\Users\r.rezino\Desktop\teste.po', 'application/octet-stream');
try
    FHttpComunication.Request.ContentType := 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + DS.Boundary;
    FHttpComunication.Request.AcceptEncoding := '';
    FHttpComunication.Request.Accept := '';
    FHttpComunication.Request.Host := '';
    FHttpComunication.Request.UserAgent := '';

    FHttpComunication.Put(UrlCmd, DS, Response);
finally
    DS.Free;
    Response.Free;
end;
```

Comment: What a surprise! I told you to use `RequestContentType` yesterday and you set boundary manually again ...

Comment: oooo sorry! I didn't see it. Create an answer and I'll accept it!