# Upload Word File to extract Text via TIKA REST

Tags: delphi, lazarus, apache-tika, indy10

I am trying to call Apache-TIKA via their REST API.  I have successfully been able to upload a PDF document and return the document's text via CURL

`curl -X PUT --data-binary @<filename>.pdf http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Content-type: application/pdf"`

That translated to INDY like so:

```
function GetPDFText(const FileName: String): String;
var
  IdHTTP:  TIdHTTP;
  Params: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdTTP.Create;
  try
    Params := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      Params.Add('file', FileName, 'application/pdf')
      Result := IdHTTP.PUT('http://localhost:9998/tika', Params);
    finally
      Params.Free;
    end;    
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Now I want to upload a word document (.docx)
I assumed that all I would need to do is change the content Type when I add my file to Params, but that doesn't seem to produce any results, although I get no error reported back.  I was able to get the following CURL command to work correctly

```
CURL -T <myDOCXfile>.docx http://localhost:9998/tika --header "Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"
```

How do I modify my HTTP call from CURL -X PUT to CURL -T?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two issues in your implementation:

1. Your translation from `CURL -X PUT` to `TIdHTTP` is wrong.
2. You don't specify `Accept` HTTP header to retrieve the extracted text in specific format.

### How to translate `curl -X PUT` to Indy?

At first, lets make it clear that `curl -X PUT --data-binary @<filename> <url>` is the same as `curl -T <filename> <url>` when:

- `<url>`'s scheme is `HTTP` or `HTTPS`
- `<url>` does not end with `/`

Therefore using one or the other shouldn't matter in your case. See also [curl documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-T).

Secondly, `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream` is designed for use with `POST` verb, however nothing can stop you from passing it to `TIdHTTP.Put`, because it is indirectly derived from TStream. There even is a dedicated [invariant of `TIdHTTP.Post`](http://ww2.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdCustomHTTP_Post@string@TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.html) method that accepts `TIdMultiPartFormDataStream`:

> function Post(AURL: string; ASource: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream): string; overload;

To upload file to the service just use `TIdHTTP.Put` method with `TFileStream` as an argument while providing proper content type of the file being uploaded in HTTP header.

And finally you're trying to extract plain text from the document, but you didn't specify content type that the service should return. This is done via `Accept` HTTP header. Default instance of `TIdHTTP` has property `IdHTTP.Request.Accept` initialized to `'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'` (this may vary depending on Indy version). Therefore by default Tika will return HTML formatted text. To get the plain text you should change it to `'text/plain; charset=utf-8'`.

Fixed implementation:

```
uses IdGlobal, IdHTTP;

function GetDocumentText(const FileName, ContentType: string): string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  Stream: TIdReadFileExclusiveStream;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := ContentType;
    Stream := TIdReadFileExclusiveStream.Create(FileName);
    try
      Result := IdHTTP.Put('http://localhost:9998/tika', Stream);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;

function GetPDFText(const FileName: string): string;
const
  PDFContentType = 'application/pdf';
begin
  Result := GetDocumentText(FileName, PDFContentType);
end;

function GetDOCXText(const FileName: string): string;
const
  DOCXContentType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document';
begin
  Result := GetDocumentText(FileName, DOCXContentType);
end;
```

According to the [Tika's documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TIKA/TikaJAXRS#TikaJAXRS-TikaResource) it also supports **posting** multipart form data. If you insist on using this approach, then you should change the target resource to `/tika/form` and switch to `Post` method in your implementation:

```
function GetDocumentText(const FileName, ContentType: string): string;
var
  IdHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  FormData: TIdMultiPartFormDataStream;
begin
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP.Request.Accept := 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
    FormData := TIdMultiPartFormDataStream.Create;
    try
      FormData.AddFile('file', FileName, ContentType); { older Indy versions: FormData.Add(...) }
      Result := IdHTTP.Post('http://localhost:9998/tika/form', FormData);
    finally
      FormData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

### Why does the original implementation in question work with PDF files?

When you `Post` multipart form data via `TIdHTTP`, Indy automatically sets content type of the request to `'multipart/form-data; boundary=...whatever...'`. This is not the case when you `Put` (unless you [set it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38613310/11562188) before performing the request) data and therefore `TIdHttp.Request.ContentType` remains blank. Now I can only guess that when Tika sees empty content type it falls back to some default type which could be PDF and it's still somehow able to read the document from multipart request.

Comment: Well said.  Much better than [the answer I posted](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,48604.msg350239.html#msg350239) to the [same question](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,48604.0.html) on the FreePascal forum.

Comment: -Peter Wolf, thanks for this great answer.  -Remy Lebeau, I read your reply in the other forum, thanks, I posted there because a few days passed without an answer on this question in SO.